# Collapse nested directories in bash

Tags: bash

Often after unzipping a file I end up with a directory containing nothing but another directory (e.g., `mkdir foo; cd foo; tar xzf ~/bar.tgz` may produce nothing but a `bar` directory in `foo`). I wanted to write a script to collapse that down to a single directory, but if there are dot files in the nested directory it complicates things a bit.

Here's a naive implementation:

```
mv -i $1/* $1/.* .
rmdir $1
```

The only problem here is that it'll also try to move `.` and `..` and ask `overwrite ./.? (y/n [n])`. I can get around this by checking each file in turn:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for file in $1/* $1/.*; do
    if [ "$file" != "$1/." ] && [ "$file" != "$1/.." ]; then
        mv -i $file .
    fi
done
rmdir $1
```

But this seems like an inelegant workaround. I tried a cleaner method using `find`:

```
for file in $(find $1); do
    mv -i $file .
done
rmdir $1
```

But `find $1` will also give `$1` as a result, which gives an error of `mv: bar and ./bar are identical`.

While the second method seems to work, is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: While the dotglob solution is cleaner, there is nothing wrong with the `find dir -type f` approach, except you should use a `while read .... done < <(find...)` loop to process it.

Comment: I'd also want to move nested directories, so I don't think `find dir -type f` alone would suffice, and `find dir -type d` has the problem of matching `dir` itself.

Comment: If you are just moving all files below a given `dir` to the current and removing `dir` when done, that shouldn't be an issue. If you need to preserve some of the nested `dirs`, then yes, the move and a second call to `find dir -type d...` may be in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on the `dotglob` shell option, which allows the your pattern to match files beginning with `.`.

```
shopt -s dotglob
mv -i "$1"/* .
rmdir "$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, consider that many `tar` implementations provide a `--strip-components` option that allows you to strip off that first path. Not sure if there is a first path?

```
tar -tf yourball.tar | awk -F/ '!s[$1]++{print$1}'
```

will show you all the first-level contents. If there is only that one directory, then

```
tar --strip-components=1 -tf yourball.tar
```

will extract the *contents* of that directory in tar into the current directory.

So that's how you can avoid the problem altogether. But it's also a solution to your immediate problem. Having extracted the files already, so you have

```
foo/bar/stuff
foo/bar/.otherstuff
```

you can do

```
tar -cf- foo | tar --strip-components=2 -C final_destination -xf-
```

The `--strip-components` feature is not part of the POSIX specification for `tar`, but it is on both the common GNU and OSX/BSD implementations.